# Which is this stotra?

Tags: identification-request, devi, stotra

Which is this Sanskrit stotra? (Starts at 24 seconds)

https://youtu.be/Tj9d44UrU7c?t=24s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *Meenakshi stotram* written by Adi Shankaracharya. But the movie makers have just replaced Minambike with Sri Rajarajeshwari.

The shloka in the video is the second half of the second couplet.

> चक्रस्थेऽचपले चराचरजगन्नाथे जगत्पूजिते
>   आर्तालीवरदे नताभयकरे वक्षोजभारान्विते ।
>    **विद्ये वेदकलापमौलिविदिते विद्युल्लताविग्रहे
>
>   मातः पूर्णसुधारसार्द्रहृदये मां पाहि मीनाम्बिके** ॥ २ ॥
>
> cakrasthe'capale carācarajagannāthe jagatpūjite
>   ārtālīvarade natābhayakare vakṣojabhārānvite ।
>    **vidye vedakalāpamaulividite vidyullatāvigrahe
>
>   mātaḥ pūrṇasudhārasārdrahṛdaye māṃ pāhi mīnāmbike** ॥ 2 ॥

The website named [stotram.co.in](http://stotram.co.in/meenakshi-stotram/) gives this stotram in differernt languages.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it would be of great help if you can take a look at this stotram also and tell me it name https://youtu.be/CnO6eK-xgY0

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao You are welcome. You can click the tick mark at the answer and accept the answer. The other video link you gave says it is Rajarajeshwari stotram. Here is the full stotram --> https://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/1330119-rare-sri-rajarajeshwari-stotra/ If you have a new question, you may ask it by clicking Ask a new question. Please take a [tour] and read [help].